# Using two " if "s sequentially

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I have sent a document to someone and I'd need to know if he has confirmed it.

I have written it as as follows, using two **" if "s** sequentially:

> I would be very grateful to you **(A)** **if** you could confirm **(B)** **if** it’s
>   Ok for you.

Is it acceptable to use two if's sequentially, at points **(A)** and **(B)** in a sentence?

**Edit** According to the first comment, I edited my sentence as follows:

> I would be very grateful to you **if** you could confirm **whether** **all is right**.

Any comment is appreciated.

**Note:** Concerning duplicate, I do not think so. Because, that mentioned question is about **comparing** “if” and “whether”, whereas, my question is about using **two sequential “if”**. My conclusion is that it would be better to use “whether” for the send one (**at least in most of the case**s.)

Comment: Using 'if' for 'whether' (your second _if_) makes some people unhappy. Otherwise, using two _if_'s together is only a style issue.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth , So, the correct form is : "I would be very grateful to you if you could confirm whether it’s Ok for you." ? Concerning “duplicate”, I do not think so. Because, that question is about comparing “if” and “whether”, whereas, my question is about using two sequential “if”. My conclusion is that it would be better to use “whether” for the send one (at least in most of the cases.) Thanks

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth , Based on your comment, I modified the sentence as follows: "I would be very grateful to you **if** you could confirm **whether all is right**." where, I also changed _"it’s Ok for you"_ to _"all is right"_ . Any comment is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Before you can address the question "Is it acceptable to use two _if_ 's sequentially,  at points A and B in a sentence?" one has to determine "Is it acceptable to use _if_  at point A in that sentence?" and "Is it acceptable to use _if_  at point B in that sentence?" ///// No; that's archaic / unidiomatic. ' ... whether it's all right with you.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth , I edited question. Thanks

Comment: Your first quoted sentence is confusing, because it looks like **(A)** and **(B)** are, literally, in the sentence itself. If that's the case, making it a sentence with referenced list items, then the sentence is incomplete. ("If I could confirm ***what***?")

Answer (score 2):

Some people might scream at the double **if**

Removing the 2nd one would solve the issue:

> I would be very grateful to you **if** you could confirm it’s OK for you.

You could further contract the statement to

> I would be very grateful if you could confirm it’s OK for you.

which removes the double **you** (from *you if you*) which might also set peoples teeth on edge.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford I was so blinded by the double *you* I forgot the one at the end!

Answer (score -1):

**Lost in the detail**

**Using two “ if ” sequentially**

> I would be very grateful to you (A) if you could confirm (B) if it’s Ok for you.
>
> Is it acceptable to use two if's sequentially, at points (A) and (B) in a sentence?

As with many of the questions posted on this site. The detail is very hard to answer because the basics are not correct. As a generalised statement Yes! you can use two "if's. However please use a correct sentence. Many of the phrases, sentences, statements and texts are not good English, even when they are grammatically correct. Any reader will note the use of bad English before any bad grammar. In fact it is easier to overlook some grammatical errors, if the text sounds good.

> I would be very grateful to you.... if you could confirm if..... it’s Ok for you.

So lets look at the sentence as it stands.
First you are grateful? for what? nobody has done anything or even knows what they should be doing?
Second If you could confirm? Confirm what?
Third it’s Ok for them? What is Ok To confirm it is OK? The mystery object is OK?

What are we talking about..... What action do you want.....express your gratitude

if you could confirm.......if it’s Ok for you.... I would be very grateful to you. Now lets look at the sentence and try it again!

Could you please confirm the document I sent.... is acceptable. .....Thank you for your co-operation.  Best regards etc